# ReactJS Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, frontend

I have a ReactJS component that passes a 'height' value to an SVG, in order to change the view of the illustration. The component and the SVG are interacted by the 'tankHeight' constant:

Component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import { ReactComponent as TanqueSVG } from '../../assets/img/tank.svg';

const Tank = ({ percent }) => {
  const tankHeight = Math.floor(340 - (percent * 2.8));

  useEffect(() => {
    const gasLevelPath = document.getElementById('gasLevelPath');
    if (gasLevelPath) {
      gasLevelPath.setAttribute('d', `M688.536 338.066H67.6509V${tankHeight}.41H688.536V338.066Z`);
    }
  }, [tankHeight]);

  return (
    <div>
      <TanqueSVG />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tank;
```

SVG:

```
<svg width="751" height="347" viewBox="0 0 751 347" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0_1027_65)">
<path d="M644.844 345.025C672.212 345.025 694.399 280.056 694.399 199.913C694.399 119.77 672.212 54.8013 644.844 54.8013C617.475 54.8013 595.288 119.77 595.288 199.913C595.288 280.056 617.475 345.025 644.844 345.025Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_1027_65)" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="1.97904" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<path opacity="0.53" d="M660.551 338.066H59.0801V63.4346H660.551C697.867 150.227 697.867 251.273 660.551 338.066Z" fill="#D3D3D3"/>
<path id="gasLevelPath" d="M688.536 338.066H67.6509V{{tankHeight}}.41H688.536V338.066Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_1027_65)"/>
...
</svg>
```

But, I am getting the following error:

`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…338.066H67.6509V{{tankHeight}}.4…".`

What can I do?